# docker-compose and django secret key

Tags: django, docker

I have build my postgres and django appplication using the following

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  django:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

When I check the docker-desktop, I got 2 docker containers, "django" and "pgdb".

When I check the django, it says

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Originally, on my windows 10 machine, I saved the secret key in the windows variable. What is the way to build the docker-compose so it has the secret get?

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a .env file with the SECRET_KEY.
In the django_secrets.env you can store like this:
SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key

Then in the docker-compose.yml file you can specify the django_secrets.env file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  django:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
        - ./django_secrets.env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

And then you can get the value in the settings.py file like this:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", 'my_default_secret_key')
```

You can have the django_secrets.env file in any path, you just need to specify the path in the docker-compose.yml file. Also you can name it as you like

Comment: how is this any more secure then having the secret key in the application hardcoded? I'm missing the part where you deploy the secrets.enf file from a secure place? If you put this file in version control you have not solved anything?